# Why namespace with empty braces is used in packages

Tags: tcl

I am having a package TEX.

```
package require ABC
package provide TEX 1.0

namespace eval ::65FGA {

}

proc ::65FGA::runSuite {{setupFile ""} args} {
Proc body
proc body
}
```

I am not getting why namespace with empty braces is used..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that

```
namespace eval ::65FGA {

}
```

bit?

[This command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M10) just creates a namespace "65FGA" and then `eval`uates an empty string (empty script if this sounds more sensible to you).  As a result, the said namespace is created but it does not yet contain anything in it.

<s>In this code, you could remove the command invocation being discussed and it won't affect anything.</s>  Hence most probably it serves narrative purpose stating clear that the package is creating the said namespace (which it then populates with at leat one `proc`edure).

**UPDATE:** Struck through the false statement (thanks to Eric Melski). The namespace must exist, indeed, before an attempt is made to create anything in it (via `proc` or `set` commands).

Comment: What do you mean by "you could remove the command invocation and it won't affect anything"?  The code shown will not work without the initial empty [namespace eval] to create the namespace.  If the namespace does not exist, Tcl will throw an error when you try to create a proc in that namespace.

Comment: @EricMelski, thanks, you're correct. I've updated my answer. My apologies to Nitesh.

Answer (score 5):

It may just be a matter of style:

```
namespace eval ::my_namespace {}
proc ::my_namespace::procname {} {...}
```

versus

```
namespace eval ::my_namespace {
    proc procname {} {...}
}
```